# Cursor and Underline missing in EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I am using an `EditText` inside a `Toolbar`, no matter what I do, cursor and underline doesn't appear

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_24dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:textCursorDrawable="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

kotlin code

```
        editText?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        editText?.requestFocus()
        editText?.isCursorVisible = true
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Where am I going wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: Please try to use SearchView instead of EditText on toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because by default the underline and cursor of EditText is of `colorAccent`. So, if you want to change their color to suppose white, then you should define a style in `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="editText" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And then apply this style as theme to edittext like this:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search..."
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:theme="@style/editText"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

1. define 4 XML files:

`edit_text_cursor.xml` a customized rectangle shape drawable, which changes the EditText's cursor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <size android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

`edit_text_underline.xml` underline shape when EditText state not focused

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`edit_text_underline_focused.xml` underline shape when EditText state focused

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`edit_text_underline_selector.xml` display different shape drawable according to the EditText state(focused or not).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_underline_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_underline" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

2. change the EditText setting as blew:

xml code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_24dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_underline_selector"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations on top of your code ? A piece of code, even if it works can't be considered as an usefull material.

Comment: I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Don't be sorry, update your post to make it fully usefull and i'll be happy to retract my downvote.

Comment: remind that the textCursorDrawable cannot use the color resource